# lua dynamically stop or manipulate a function

Tags: lua

What I want to do is to dynamically stop a function in lua. My code that i tried:

```lua
local SaveReal = Thread
local stopped  = false

--[[
Thread function runs the lua function
that it includes in a separate thread.
It was created before here
and is trying to be manipulated here.
]]--
Thread = function(func)
  SaveReal(function()
    while(not stopped) do
      func()
    end
  end)
end

Thread(function()
  while(true) do
    print("Thread working")
  end
end)
```

Maybe if I could read the contents of the function as a string, I could load it into my manipulative function with load. so the code would not work if my flag is not false.

Comment: Lua is single thread environment, can you provide more details about what you're using to create the threads? also if you remove the second while loop you might get the behavior you want `Thread(function() print("Thread working") end)`

Comment: what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

Lua has something called [Coroutines](https://www.lua.org/pil/9.html) to provide multi-tasking (not multi-threading).